# How to assign one specific color to a specific taxa in a phyloseq object after using colorRampPalette

Tags: r, color-palette, phyloseq

I have difficulties on R for creating the color palette i'd like to get...
I simply want to plot distributions of the different phyla of my phyloseq object (called physeq) in barplots.
In order to assign a color to each phylum (so the color doesn't change after subsetting the phyloseq object), I used these lines :

**See how many phyla are in the whole dataset:**

```
length(table(tax_table(physeq)[,"Phylum"])) #I have 28 different phyla
```

**Create a random color palette with 28 different colors:**

```
color = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]

getPalette = colorRampPalette(sample(color, 28,replace=F))
```

**Assign one color to one phylum:**

```
PhylumList = unique(tax_table(physeq)[,"Phylum"])

PhylumPalette = getPalette(length(PhylumList))

names(PhylumPalette) = PhylumList
```

---

However, I have a phylum called "undetermined_Eukaryota" that I would like it to have the color black.

Do you have a solution to get **in a same palette** :

1. a random color palette for 27 phyla

and

2. a color fixed as black for the phylum "undetermined_Eukaryota"

Thank you very very much for you help!

Comment: After executing the code in your question, you have a named vector of colors. So if I'm not mistaken you can simply replace whatever color "undetermined_Eukaryota" had with black: `PhylumPalette["undetermined_Eukaryota"] = "#000000"` without touching the rest of the palette.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was indeed that simple!